# Looking for CeStub description or the tech docs for wince v6

Tags: windows-ce

Client has a major name brand hmi using WinCE v6.  It has been identified that a network scan is causing a windows error to display saying CeStub.exe has crashed. It only happens on these 3 hmis that all perform the same function.  Client wants to know what the file is and why it is being used. It is part of the hmi ROM and cannot be copied or deleted. The cestub file is located in the windows folder.

Tried to copy or delete the file to see what breaks, but the OS refuses to do either because it's part of the ROM.  Been looking for 3 days for the tech docs.

Can someone tell me what this file does or point me to the technical documentation?